# Count number of occurrences in Pandas column with some multiples

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, where-clause, series

I have a Pandas dataframe with a column called `specialty` that looks like this:

```
0         1,5
1           1
2           1
3           1
4           1
5         1,5
6           3
7           3
8           1
9         1,3
10          1
11    1,2,4,6
```

I want to count the number of occurrences of each number. If there is more than one value for a certain cell, I would want it to be added to the count of `7`, but I'd also like each number in that cell to be added to its respective total. For example, for this data my desired output would look something like this:

```
1: 10
2: 1
3: 3
4: 1
5: 2
6: 1
7: 4
```

The `7` here is referring to the fact that there are 4 rows with multiple values. However, each of those numbers should be added to the overall count for each number.

Here's what I have so far, but it only counts multiples instead of also each number in the multiple. I'm also computing the percentage of each value.

```
# Convert specialties with more than 1 to item 7 (multiple)
part_chars['specialty'] = np.where(part_chars['specialty'].str.len() > 1, 7, part_chars['specialty'])

counts = part_chars.specialty.value_counts()
percs = part_chars.specialty.value_counts(normalize=True)*100
pd.concat([counts,percs], axis=1, keys=['count', 'percentage'])
```

And the output:

```
   count    percentage
7   213     40.804598
1   211     40.421456
3   39      7.471264
5   23      4.406130
6   13      2.490421
4   12      2.298851
2   11      2.107280
```

I'm not sure how to make the counts work the way I want them. Would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split by the `,` and explode to get value counts of unique values. Then count the `,` rows and assign it to `7`

```py
out = df['specialty'].str.split(',').explode().value_counts()
out.loc[7] = df['specialty'].str.contains(',').sum()
# or in one line
out = pd.concat([df['specialty'].str.split(',').explode().value_counts(),
                 pd.Series([df['specialty'].str.contains(',').sum()], index=[7])])
```

```
print(out)

1    10
3     3
5     2
2     1
4     1
6     1
7     4
Name: specialty, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) to get dummies for the values and use [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) to get the counts and then concat the series with the value of 7 which is the next index value i.e. len(the_series_with_value_counts) + 1.

```
out = df["speciality"].str.get_dummies(",").sum()
out = pd.concat(
    [out, 
     pd.Series(df["speciality"].str.find(",").ne(-1).sum(), index=[str(len(out) + 1)])]
)
print(out)

1    10
2     1
3     3
4     1
5     2
6     1
7     4
```

Comment: This works and I like it, but I'm not familiar with `get_dummies()` or `.ne()`, I feel the other answer is a little bit more intuitive.